# Persecution of philosophers?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

What examples are there of philosophers being persecuted, but not to for their political views or religion?

All I can think of is Socrates, Plato's teacher, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

On June 22, 1936, Moritz Schlick was [murdered](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Moritz_Schlick#Schlick.27s_Murder) by his student, Johann Nelböck. Nelböck claimed Schlick's anti-metaphysical philosophy had morally corrupted him. It is reported as well that Schlick had rejected Nelböcks thesis (see Ray Monk's [biography of Wittgenstein](https://www.scribd.com/mobile/document/223213899/Monk-Ray-Ludwig-Wittgenstein-the-Duty-of-Genius)).

Some additional references: [The Murder of Moritz Schlick](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-16561-5_13) by F. Stadler, [Wittgenstein In Vienna](https://books.google.com/books?id=QQkvc_PeW7EC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=moritz+schlick+murdered&source=bl&ots=2JvpuU8kbh&sig=t_nGCaz2TE1Z3k8dYkwGUEYTrFI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbxOGNo5XRAhWN14MKHYu9ADYQ6AEIVDAJ#v=onepage&q=moritz%20schlick%20murdered&f=false) by By Allan S. Janik, Hans Veigl. Two wikipedia articles: [Schlick's murder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moritz_Schlick#Schlick.27s_murder) and [Nelböck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Nelb%C3%B6ck).

> Nelböck was found guilty and sentenced, but in the event he became a
>   distorted cause célèbre, around which crystallized the growing
>   nationalist and anti-Jewish sentiments in the city. Although a German
>   Protestant from minor Prussian nobility, Schlick was subsequently
>   characterized in the press as a pivotal figure in disaffected Jewish
>   circles, and the murder was applauded by Vienna's austrofascists.

Comment: This sounds like Hitchcock's *Rope*!

Comment: Interesting and sad, I didn't know about Schlick's murder.